# How to provide openId login to wicket app?

Tags: security, spring, openid, wicket

I am looking for a tutorial/guide or sample app. I would prefer something standards based, ideally something using Spring Security.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at this wicket component:
http://www.xaloon.org/blog/vytautas.racelis/Xaloon_SignIn_panel_for_Apache_Wicket-Login_via_Facebook_Google_Linked_Twitter_and_Yahoo

As I have understood, it is based on SpringSecurity.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. It looked good initially but after attempting to use it and finding the dependencies were not resolvable easily the project seems somewhat dead.

Comment: I'm using this components and they are working for me. Although you can copy and paste only code, that is required for you or just use it as example.